# Embedded System USB to Android Device

Tags: android, embedded, linux-device-driver

I am writing an Android 2.1 application that needs to get data from a USB device. The USB device is an embedded system i created. The embedded system has no OS. Also, the android device does not send any data to the embedded system.

How should i go about this, I'm guessing i will need to make a high-level driver to communicate from USB to the application. But, i have never made a Linux driver before.

If creating a high-level driver is the best way to do this, can someone give me some references so i have somewhere to start.

If there are other ways to accomplish this i would also like to hear about it

-Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Android Open Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html) is where you should start looking. Like many of other Google's documents, the tutorial is reasonably complete and should provide you with a good starting point

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to recompile Android kernel to add usb device support.
It can be an option if you are working on some dedicated project and only one Android phone should be supported. If you want to support all kinds of Android phones, I can suggest to implement USB host in your embedded system( if it is possible), thus your Android phone can be connected using [ADB](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) protocol.